# How do I find out what Content Type a SharePoint list is?

Tags: list, content-type

Hopefully this will be pretty straight forward? I'm cataloguing the Lists on some SP lists and need to know what Content Types they are, Base Data Entry, Items, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to

> Site Contents > List  > Settings (click on the ellipse `...` next to the list name) > Scroll down to the content type section.

[image]

Below has `item` content type only

[image]

**Update**

If you cant see the content types -

> Go to settings > advanced settings.

[image]

> Set `Allow management of content types` to `Yes`

[image]

Comment: I was ready to slap my forehead but I can't see the that under the List Settings. Might I not have the right permissions to view it?

Comment: Updated the answer :)